# regplot using datetime64 as the x axis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn, regplot

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
date         score  
2017-06-04    90
2017-06-03    80
2017-06-02    70
```

When I tried this:

```
sns.regplot(x=date, y=score, data=df)
```

I got an error:

```
TypeError: reduction operation 'mean' not allowed for this dtype
```

The dtype for date is `datetime64[ns]`, and `int64` for the score column.

How can I covert the `date` column so that `regplot` will work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seaborn doesn't support datetimes in `regplot` but here's an ugly hack:

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
df['date_f'] = pd.factorize(df['date'])[0] + 1
mapping = dict(zip(df['date_f'], df['date'].dt.date))

ax = sns.regplot('date_f', 'score', data=df)
labels = pd.Series(ax.get_xticks()).map(mapping).fillna('')
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

produces

[image]

This is the main approach used in time-series regression. If you have daily data, you code day 1 as 1 and increase the number as the days go by. This assumes you have a regularly-spaced time series.