# Python: can I convert a datetime to a float with granularity lesser than a whole day?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, seaborn

I am trying to plot blood pressure readings, each of which has a datetime timestamp with the day and hour:minute:second of the reading.

As many Seaborn regression plots (lmplot, regplot etc) do not support datetime timestamps I resorted to creating a new data frame column with a numeric ordinal like below:

```
from datetime import date
df['date_ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda date: date.toordinal())
```

this works, but the problem is that multiple readings taken in the same day are all stacked on the same x-axis point.

Are there better functions than to ordinal to achieve separating readings taken on a same day with decimal values after the day ordinal?

Comment: Is this what you are expecting ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860428/passing-datetime-like-object-to-seaborn-lmplot

Comment: No. that posts tells you how to plot values on a x-axis with datetime values, which is not supported as per that post. I go around this problem converting a datetime timestamp to an integer (days from 01 Jan 1970) using the toordinal() function, but this gives an integer with the day and discards the h:mm:ss part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the `timedelta`s between every `datetime` in the `date` column and the oldest `datetime`, then use the `timedelta`'s seconds. This means calculating the relative time (in seconds) since the oldest timestamp:

```
df['seconds_since_start'] = df['date'].apply(lambda date: (date - df['date'].min()).seconds)
```

From here, you can convert the seconds to days (with decimal values) using basic math:

```
df['days_since_start'] = df['seconds_since_start'] / (60 * 60 * 24)
```

Comment: You probably want `.total_seconds()` instead of `.seconds`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jfaccioni for hinting towards the right direction :)
Here's what I did.

First of all to convert a datetime object to a float, so that it could be used by seaborn's scatterplot.

I used the timestamp function which converts a datetime to an epoch (seconds from 01-jan-1970):

```
df['date_ordinal'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Measurement Date']).apply(lambda date: date.timestamp())
```

with that I have solved my need. Just to help someone with similar requirements here's a second part.

How to transform back those large seconds numbers back to date strings so they can be used as labels for my seaborn x-axis plot:

```
# now convert the epoch values back to a YYYY-MM-DD string for the x labels
# localtime converts the epoch into a datetime object abd strftime converts it into a string
new_labels = [time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d',time.localtime(item)) for item in ax.get_xticks()]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```